Officeライセンス更新に必要な、プロキシ設定を教えてください
現在、オフライン環境でOffice2021を使用しております。
1年に一度、オンライン環境への接続（ライセンス更新？）が必要とのことでした。
現在の環境はプロキシサーバーでネットワーク制限をかけています。
Officeライセンスの更新に必要なプロキシの設定をどなたか教えてください。
以下、実施内容、その他です。
【検証内容】

Edgeで「microsoft.com」へアクセスできることを確認
ウイルス対策ソフトの停止
「.microsoft.com」、「ctldl.windowsupdate.com」へのアクセス許可をプロキシに設定
「Execel→アカウント→更新オプション→今すぐ更新（U)」という作業実施後「問題が発生しました。ネットワーク接続を確認し、しばらくしてからやり直せ」
エラーコード「30183-27(403)」
ログを確認したところ、エラーコード「30183-27(403)」の表示
エラーコードで検索しましたが、ピンときませんでした。

以上になります。
必要情報等ございましたら、質問下さい。
わかる範囲でお答えいたします。
宜しくお願いいたします。

「４．作業実施後」の”作業”とは何を指していますか？

作業実施は、Execel→アカウント→更新オプション→今すぐ更新（U）
になります。

こんな記事が参考になるかも。office2021のライセンス認証のためのURLを確認したい, ライセンスを確認できません「Microsoft Office Home and Business2021」オフラインで更新について

ありがとうございます。
明日、業務中に記事の内容実施してみます。

プロキシサーバーで許可の設定するために、ライセンス認証でアクセスするサイトを知りたいという事でよろしいでしょうか？
Office 2021についての資料は見つけられませんでしたが、Office 365についての資料を見つけました。
Microsoft 365 から Office をアクティブ化するとアカウントに接続できない - Microsoft 365 Apps | Microsoft Learn#手順 3: ファイアウォールの内側にいるかどうかを確認する
ここに記載されている全てのサイトにアクセスできるようにプロキシサーバーを設定すればうまくいく可能性があります。もし、それでもうまくいかない場合は、プロキシサーバーのログを一つ一つ確認しながら開けていくしかありません。
なお、質問の4.の作業はOfficeの更新であってライセンス認証は関係ありません。もちろん、エラーコードもライセンス認証とは関係ありません。ライセンスが認証されているかどうかわからないというのであれば、任意のOffice製品(WordやExcel)で「アカウント」の画面を質問文に貼り付けてみてください。
